# how to store class name in local storage

Tags: html, local-storage

is there a way to store a class name in localstorage ?? If there is a way how to do it ??

There is a panel which is hidden at the beginning, by clicking on the button panel shows, i would like to store information, after click, whether the panel is hidden or shown

my jquery code

```
$("#button").click(function () {
        $("#searchWraper").slideToggle(1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code to add a callback

```
$("#searchWraper").slideToggle(1000, ToggleDisplayStatus());
```

Making use of these methods to store information in LocalStorage (with Cookie fallback...)

```
function setLocalStorage(c_name, value) {
    var exdays = 30;
    // if localStorage is present, use that
    if (('localStorage' in window) && window.localStorage !== null) {
        localStorage[c_name] = value;
    } else {
        var exdate = new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }
}

function getLocalStorage(c_name) {
    // if localStorage is present, use that
    if (('localStorage' in window) && window.localStorage !== null) {
        return localStorage[c_name];
    } else {
        var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
            x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (x == c_name) {
                return unescape(y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, after clicking on the button the omniscient console says ToggleDisplayStatus is not defined

Comment: You'll need to create that method yourself!! Something along the lines of `function ToggleDisplayStatus() { panelVisible = !panelVisible; setLocalStorage('panelVisible', panelVisible); }`

Comment: Give this a read: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ it will help explain how the "callback" feature works and how to implement it.

Comment: I read the text that You did to me and I understand how it works callback but I have no idea how to write this method if you can help me with this?

Comment: well, i pasted the first part to script.js file and the second to local.js, after clicking on the button (the green one button under the header) alert says what is the state of the panel but nothing is storage (after refreshing site the panel is in the same state) http://fama.net.pl/test/

Comment: This pretty much goes beyond just answering your initial question but neverthless - http://jsfiddle.net/ShFsG/8/

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME! you helped me a lot, if I could I would have kissed you, you have a pint for me, I hope that someday I will be able to repay

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some js function to do that

example

```
<div id="button" value="myvariable" onClick="clickfunc(this.value)">CLICK ME</div>
```

Javascript

```
function click(x)
{
    //x is value from onclick button
}
```